# Finding which points falls within a specific polygon

Tags: polygon, spatial, shapefile

I have a dataframe from boat track GPS that looks like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(
>     Lat = c(48.83, 48.84, 48.63),
>     Long = c(-125.02, -125.05, -125.035)
>     Time = c(13:02, 13:04, 13:05) )
```

I would like to know which ones of those points are in US waters and in Canadian waters. I have been trying to find load a border shapefile from the rnaturalearth package but I am not sure those include waters as well. I am confused on when I find the border file, I should keep it as a shapefile or use if as a sf object (but then the geometry is a polygon, does it matter?). I have been trying `st_within`, `st_intersects()` I have found similar posts online, but nothing seems to work. Thank you for your help.